# Elasticsearch: union of several sorted and limited queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to execute two queries, get the union of these two and then sort and limit the combined results.

The queries are just term queries:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": { "a.field": "A" }
  },
  "sort": [
     { "another.field": {"order": "desc"}}
  ],
  "size": 25
}
```

I looked at dis_max query but the queries cannot be sorted and limited separately.

The equivalent SQL would be:

```
select * from (
  (select * from my_table where a_field="A" order by another_field desc limit 25)
  union
  (select * from my_table where a_field="B" order by another_field desc limit 25)
) t order by yet_another_field limit 25;
```

There is still another part to this query that is way faster in elasticsearch than in a relational database. That is why I'd like to see this working in elasticsearch. Is it possible?

**EDIT**

Using terms query with both values "A" and "B" is not an option. This is because when sorted by "another.field", no "B" documents may make it to the result set in order to be sorted later by "yet_another_field".

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": { "a.field": ["A","B"] }
  },
  "sort": [
     { "another.field": {"order": "desc"}}
  ],
  "size": 25
}
```

The query is : `25 results` from Documents where the value of `a.field is either A or B` sorted by `another.field` in descending order

Comment: I forgot to mention why this is not an option. The problem with this approach is that e.g. documents with the value "B" might not be in the result set if they are sorted with the "A" documents. So in practice, the result set for "terms": { "a.field": ["A","B"] } is exactly the same as "term": { "a.field": "A" }. I will add this to the question.

Comment: That may happen with your union query as well, isnt it ? So do you want documents where A and B both are present ?

Comment: The union query ensures that 25 A's and 25 B's will be ordered by yet_another_field.

Comment: Example: There are two families - A and B. A has two children: Tom (age 5) and Cheryl (age 8). B has three children: Ben (1), John-John (4) and Rachel (6). I want get the youngest two children of each family, sort them by their name and then limit the result to 2 children. With the terms query, I would always return Ben and John-John when the correct result would be Ben and Cheryl.

Comment: Ok.. now I get it. Let me check this.